# Passing data from a from to bootstrap modal using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I wanted to pass a data to a modal from this `textbox` using `PHP`

**Textbox code:**

```
 <input type="text" id="weights" class="form-control" placeholder="Weight (lbs)" name="weight">
```

**This is the button code:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" id="buttonx">Submit</button>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#exampleModalCenter').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var weight = document.getElementById("weights");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'showResult.php',
      data: 'weight=' + weight,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#fetched-data').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Modal Code:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Results</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="fetched-data">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$data=$_POST["weight"];
echo "The weight is $data";
?>
```

When i click the button, nothing really shows up. Even the modal, doesn't show up.

Comment: Any error in console? Also note that, `document.getElementById("weights");` get `Object` not `value`

Comment: it's normal nothing happened, do you use jquery first - second where is your div id = feteched data ? i can't see nowhere ? We need also the showresult.php

Comment: problem with your show results ! just echo "$data"; to begin and var_dump your $ data in your submit.php ...

Answer (score -1):

PROBLEMS IN YOUR CODE

1. First of all your not getting the value in weights variable.
2. You are not able to trigger modal because of data-target attribute.
3. You are not able to pass value to your ajax call.

BELOW SOLUTION MIGHT SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM:

Hope this pen -> https://codepen.io/afzal_coder/pen/rpKdgK solve your query.

and add this code to your php file.

```
<?php 
$data = $_POST['weight'];
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: Except the Number 1, rest are wrong, is it possible to  trigger modal with data-target and also can pass value to ajax. This is not really answer of this question.

Comment: Please refer to the screenshot:-> https://prnt.sc/hzt6ge I'm able to retrieve the value which the user has typed in textbox.

Comment: So? I know it's possible to pass textbox value to modal. But the number 2 and 3 are wrong, both are possible.

Comment: I've tried the pen @KhanAfzal, but it still doesn't show me something even though I've typed in somethign on the textbox.

Comment: I have this error on the console.

ncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ((index):129)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
  ......

Comment: Hi, @KhanAfzal, thanks for your pen. It seems that there is a problem with my jquery library. I've tried the ones you have and it somehow works.